# Resistor as an ideal machine

Tags: thermodynamics, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, dissipation

Isn't a resistor an ideal machine? It can convert electrical energy into thermal with an (or almost?) 100% efficiency.

Comment: Now I understood that my question was stupid, with the same confidence i could say that gravitation is also ideal machine because it converts potential energy into kinetic with 100% efficiency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In thermodynamics an engine converts energy (heat) into work. A resistor just converts energy (potential energy) into heat and doesn't do any work in the process.

The efficiency of an engine is the percentage of the energy passing through that gets converted to work i.e. a 100% efficient engine converts all the energy passing through it to work. So if you insist on calling a resistor an engine (which it isn't since it was never designed to produce work) then it is a $0$% efficient engine.